# Select list of node by innertext. Issue XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I have following Xml

```
<Main>
         <Order Id="1262">
            <Product>
               <Name>Prod1</Name>
                   <Barcode>1234</Barcode>
                </Product>
                 <Product>
                   <Name>Prod1</Name>
                   <Barcode>1234</Barcode>
                </Product>
                <Product>
                     <Name>Prod2</Name>
                   <Barcode>2345</Barcode>
               </Product>

            </Order>

        <Order Id="1263">
               <Product>
               <Name>Prod1</Name>
                   <Barcode>1234</Barcode>
                </Product>
                 <Product>
                   <Name>Prod1</Name>
                   <Barcode>1234</Barcode>
                </Product>
                <Product>
                     <Name>Prod2</Name>
                   <Barcode>2345</Barcode>
               </Product>
                </Order>
</Main>


XmlDocument xml=new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(path);
```

Now I want to select only nodes whose barcode is 1234 from Node whose `orderId=1263`. My code is

```
 string OrderId="1262"
   string ReadedBarcode ="1234"

    XmlNode ONode = xml.SelectSingleNode("//Order[@Id='" + OrderId + "']");
     XmlNodeList BarCodeNodeList = ONode.SelectNodes("//Product/Barcode[text()='" + ReadedBarcode + "']");
```

But I dont know why all the nodes from document having innertext `1234` are getting selected. that means even node from `<Order Id="1263">` this node is getting selected.

Any Solutions?

Comment: Are you stuck with XmlDocument, or can you use XDocument? I ask because the querying ability of XML to Linq against an XDocument makes this task simpler to express than the XPath solution you are working with here.

Comment: I totally agree with u, but my project is somewhat big, and i have come lot further now to change base. and deadline is also not too far, So cant use Linq To Xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
        XmlDocument xml=new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(path);
        string OrderId = "1262";
        string ReadedBarcode = "1234";

        XmlNodeList BarCodeNodeList = xml.SelectNodes("//Order[@Id='" + OrderId + "']"+"//Product/Barcode[text()='" + ReadedBarcode + "']");
```

Also, your XML is invalid, it is missing some start  tags, it should be

```
<Main>
  <Order Id="1262">
    <Product>
    <Name>Prod1</Name>
    <Barcode>1234</Barcode>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <Name>Prod1</Name>
      <Barcode>1234</Barcode>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <Name>Prod2</Name>
      <Barcode>2345</Barcode>
    </Product>

  </Order>

  <Order Id="1263">
    <Product>
    <Name>Prod1</Name>
    <Barcode>1234</Barcode>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <Name>Prod1</Name>
      <Barcode>1234</Barcode>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <Name>Prod2</Name>
      <Barcode>2345</Barcode>
    </Product>
  </Order>
</Main>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you wrote that you are 'stuck' with XmlDocument, but the reason you gave sounded like a decision not based on the technical constraints, rather on preference. I believe in a tool-for-the-job, so please forgive me for writing a solution you may not like, but it might persuade you of the merits in using XDocument where you see the benefit.

The XML you posted was not syntactically correct, the sample below shows the corrections where I have added the missing Product starter nodes.

Here's what I would suggest, code written in LinqPad. The Dump() method just spits the variable out to a console. Also, I did not know which 'node' you wanted to find, so I am returning the Order node in this sample.

Cheers, Aaron

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"
<Main>
    <Order Id=""1262"">
        <Product>
            <Name>Prod1</Name>
            <Barcode>1234</Barcode>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name>Prod1</Name>
            <Barcode>1234</Barcode>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name>Prod2</Name>
            <Barcode>2345</Barcode>
        </Product>
    </Order>
    <Order Id=""1263"">
        <Product>
            <Name>Prod1</Name>
            <Barcode>1234</Barcode>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name>Prod1</Name>
            <Barcode>1234</Barcode>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name>Prod2</Name>
            <Barcode>2345</Barcode>
        </Product>
    </Order>
</Main>
");

var barcode = "1234";
var orderId = "1263";
var found = (
    from row in doc.Root.Descendants("Order")
    where 
      row.Attribute("Id") != null && 
      row.Attribute("Id").Value == orderId && 
      row.Descendants("Barcode").Any(a => a.Value == barcode)
    select row).ToList();

found.Dump();
```

Comment: Which node did you want to select/output from the query? The Barcode, Product or Order?

Comment: Ok, then the query would have to be reversed to select Root.Descendents("Barcode") so the Barcode element is output. In any case @CeeTee's solution gets what you needed and requires less change.